# Set initial values on cascade Select in Angular

Tags: angularjs, cascadingdropdown

I'm trying to set initial values from the model in **cascaded** Select elements.

All the models have initial values. The view is like this:

```
**1)** <select id="ddN_Universitate" ng-model="CandidatInfo.ID_N_UniversitateAbsolvita" ng-change="N_FACULTATEListByN_UNIVERSITATE(CandidatInfo.ID_N_UniversitateAbsolvita)" ng-options="u.ID_ELEMENT as u.DENUMIRE for u in ListN_UniversitatiInfo">
    <option value=''>Selecteaza</option>
</select>

<br />

**2) depends on 1)**
N_Facultate {{CandidatInfo.ID_N_FacultateAbsolvita}}
<select id="ddN_Facultate" ng-model="CandidatInfo.ID_N_FacultateAbsolvita" ng-change="N_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIUListByN_FACULTATE(CandidatInfo.ID_N_FacultateAbsolvita)" ng-options="f.ID_ELEMENT as f.DENUMIRE for f in ListN_FacultatiInfo">
    <option value=''>Selecteaza</option>
</select>

<br />

**3) depends on 2)**
N_Program {{CandidatInfo.ID_N_ProgramStudiuAbsolvit}}
<select id="ddN_ProgramStudiu" ng-model="CandidatInfo.ID_N_ProgramStudiuAbsolvit" ng-options="p.ID_ELEMENT as p.DenumireCompletaRMU for p in ListN_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIUInfo">
    <option value=''>Selecteaza</option>
</select>
```

For id="ddN_Universitate", the value is set, but for the following Selects, the values from the model are not set because they depend on calling the "ng-change" event handler.

The controller is like this:

```
$scope.LoadUniversitati = function () {

    factoryRMU.callGetService("N_UNIVERSITATE/N_UNIVERSITATEListByAnUniversitar?iD_AnUniv=" + $id_anuniv)
        .then(function (response) {
            var fullResult = angular.fromJson(response);
            //var CandidatInfo = JSON.parse(fullResult.data);
            $scope.ListN_UniversitatiInfo = fullResult.data;
        },
            function (data) {
                console.log("Unknown error occurred calling N_UNIVERSITATEListByAnUniversitar");
                console.log(data);
            });
};

$scope.N_FACULTATEListByN_UNIVERSITATE = function (iD_UNIVERSITATE) {

    factoryRMU.callGetService("N_FACULTATE/N_FACULTATEListByN_UNIVERSITATE?iD_UNIVERSITATE="+ iD_UNIVERSITATE + "&iD_AnUniv=" + $id_anuniv)
        .then(function (response) {
            var fullResult = angular.fromJson(response);
            //var CandidatInfo = JSON.parse(fullResult.data);
            $scope.ListN_FacultatiInfo = fullResult.data;
        },
            function (data) {
                console.log("Unknown error occurred calling N_FACULTATEListByN_UNIVERSITATE");
                console.log(data);
            });
};


$scope.N_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIUListByN_FACULTATE = function (iD_Facultate) {

    factoryRMU.callGetService("N_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIU/N_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIUListByN_FACULTATE?iD_ELEMENT=" + iD_Facultate + "&iD_AnUniv=" + $id_anuniv)
        .then(function (response) {
            var fullResult = angular.fromJson(response);
            //var CandidatInfo = JSON.parse(fullResult.data);
            $scope.ListN_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIUInfo = fullResult.data;
        },
            function (data) {
                console.log("Unknown error occurred calling N_PROGRAM_DE_STUDIUListByN_FACULTATE");
                console.log(data);
            });
};


$scope.LoadUniversitati();
```

So, are there any possibilities?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select id="ddN_Universitate" ng-model="CandidatInfo.ID_N_UniversitateAbsolvita" ng-change="N_FACULTATEListByN_UNIVERSITATE(CandidatInfo.ID_N_UniversitateAbsolvita)">
  <option value=''>Selecteaza</option>
  <option ng-repeat="u in ListN_UniversitatiInfo" value="{{u.ID_ELEMENT}}">{{u.ELEMENT_LABEL}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: so, this is the first Select, which does not depend on anything. It is set via the model. The second and the third, marked with 1) and 2) in my code are not selected even if the model is already set

Comment: l added plunker: 1) https://plnkr.co/edit/ECqpjdV8SjMHY0VYBTKH?p=preview if you change singleSelect to be null you will get the "not selected" option but if the model is set you will get the option value